# Phrase to describe a page with 2500 years of events

Tags: word-choice

A bit of background: we're developing a free educational website that would show a hundred or so famous historic events on a single page, spanning about 2500 years. And we're looking for a phrase to reflect that the user would be able to grasp all those events at once.

The phrase we've come up with is **"A broad look at our history"** *
Or maybe **"A wide view of the history"**.

None of us is a native speaker, so we're asking for a validation here: is any of those correct and applicable? If not, please advice something to reflect the idea.

Thanks!

* *The whole phrase would actually be more dramatic

"People, Events, Epochs... A wide view of our history"*

Comment: is this an inappropriate question for the community?

Comment: Look for synonyms of *summary*.

Comment: A colloquial expression like “a view from 60,000 feet” might work. In order to get 2500 years onto a single page, you will inevitably miss quite a few things. An expression that connotes blurring and distortion of detail through the viewing process may be more satisfying to the viewer.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica, we're trying to, mm, cherry-pick events that would kind of summarise the history. So, it's a summary, yes, yet we want to let the user see the bigger picture by themself. Not sure if this makes sense. Anyhow, you're making a good point though, thanks! I'll check the synonyms for something that would fit!

Comment: @GlobalCharm, "to get 2500 years onto a single page, you will inevitably miss quite a few things" -- uhh, that's true! Quite a few! I think, behind the "broad view" expression, I had a picture of a painter, drawing something and then leaning back to see the work as whole. Maybe, humanizing the size of millennia. **While definitely losing some important parts** . Thank you for understanding the issue and for the “view from 60,000 feet” -- I'll suggest that to my mates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to EL&U!

We wouldn't say "A wide view of **the** history". ("The history" is always "The history OF somewhere/something") "A wide view" is OK. Or perhaps "a broad view".

If it really is '**Our** history', you can safely add 'our' to any of the following suggestions:

> People, Events, Epochs... A panorama of history

or

> People, Events, Epochs... A tapestry of history

or (but these need 'The'):

> People, Events, Epochs... The sweep of history
>
> People, Events, Epochs... The broad sweep of history
>
> People, Events, Epochs... The great sweep of history)

or (but these words are plain, and undramatic):

> People, Events, Epochs... A bird's-eye  view of history
>
> People, Events, Epochs... An aerial view of history

It's a bit difficult to suggest that the reader might grasp all the events at once. Is it necessary? Views and tapestries can at least be SEEN at once. "At a glance" is the usual expression. [If you see something at a glance, you see or recognize it immediately, and without having to think or look carefully.] But it is a very common formula, and has no drama at all! "In one gulp" is better: slightly wrong but perfectly comprehensible and mildly amusing.

In fact, try adding 'in one gulp' to any of the suggestions above.

> People, Events, Epochs... The broad sweep of our history - in one gulp.

I think that works well if your site is mostly for young people. It also guards against any accusations of pomposity. If your site is more academic, more serious, then we can't use 'gulp', and even 'at a glance' might suggest the site lacks seriousness and depth.

Comment: Old Brixtonian, thank you for explaining how to phrase correctly the initial sentence and for suggesting so many others! And special thanks for the "in one gulp" addition -- we truly might've gone too pompous there 